# Which keyboard layout should I choose?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I'm using Windows 7 ultimate, my laptop keyboard is shown in the image below

[image]

I didn't find an adequate layout keyboard that fits my physical one, I've tried the spanish traditional, latino-american, and spanish variant but no one has the "**[**" symbol on the 8 key and "**{**" on the 7 key.

Comment: What is the make and model of your laptop?

Comment: Sony vaio vpcf11z1e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### I didn't find an adequate layout keyboard that fits my physical one

You have a Portugese keyboard.

[image]

Source [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY)

Answer (score 0):

Pls this is how my keyboard is
But when I type it does not show me words based on this layout but based on the normal layout where the open bracket is on 9
What should I do

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: maybe you have to change the system typing language to portugese to match the phisical keyboard